format issues when redirecting to docker logs with json logger
I am trying to redirect logs from a certain process to the docker logs, and i am achieving the same using a redirection using > /proc/1/fd/1 and this works perfectly fine.
I then introduce a json logger to format my logs before sending them to the docker logs. The logs is getting printed but not in the format expected. It just prints the message as is without the formatting that was introduced by the json logger.
Here is a snippet:
#!/bin/bash 
set -x

# Json logger
IFS= read -r -d '' __JQ_LOGGER_SCRIPT <<'JQSCRIPT'
{
  "type": "log",
  "host": $host,
  "level": $level,
  "systemid": $systemid,
  "system": "connect-manager",
  "time": $time,
  "timezone": $timezone,
#  "message": .
  "log": .
}
JQSCRIPT

json_logger() {
  jq \
    --raw-input \
    --compact-output \
    --arg level "$1" \
    --arg systemid "app-manager-`cat /etc/machine-id`"\
    --arg host `hostname`.${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}\
    --arg time `date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ'`\
    --arg timezone `date +%Z`\
    "$__JQ_LOGGER_SCRIPT"
}

echo "Starting App manager" | json_logger INFO > /proc/1/fd/1
(

echo "App manager terminated due to signal $?" | json_logger INFO > /proc/1/fd/1

)& 

I also tried passing the log message as a second argument to the json logger but it didnt help.
echo "App manager terminated due to signal $?" | json_logger INFO, "App manager terminated due to signal $?" > /proc/1/fd/1

This the kind of log I see in the docker logs
+ jq --raw-input --compact-output --arg name INFO --arg systemid app-manager-868d754f49b140148f55d7aeb59d37d5 --arg host app-wm-app1-7bc64b546b-cgkj6.ns--arg time 2024-07-26T07:58:33.505Z --arg timezone UTC --arg log '' ''
"App manager terminated due to signal 137"

This script works fine when run as is, and as I introduce the redirection I see issues.

I see several issues with what you are doing. First, there is no comment character in JSON, so get rid of the #  "message": . line. Also, all the "values" need to be enclosed in quotes. So, your JQSCRIPT should look like this:
{
  "type": "log",
  "host": "$host",
  "level": "$level",
  "systemid": "$systemid",
  "system": "connect-manager",
  "time": "$time",
  "timezone": "$timezone",
  "log": "."
}

Don't use the --raw-input option to jq. I, personally, don't see a use case for that option. It turns jq into cat. Also, why are you using --compat-output? This will make all the output be on a single line. Is that what you want? If so, why not just use an echo statement:
echo '{"type": "log", "host": "'$(hostname).${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}'", "level": "'$1'", "systemid": "app-manager-'$(cat /etc/machine-id)'", "system": "connect-manager", "time": "'$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ')'", "timezone": "'$(date +%Z)'", "log": "."}'

Looks like to me, the 'JQSCRIPT' isn't a script to be passed to jq, but instead the input to jq. Then, based on the variables you are setting, it will give you the output you are looking for.
So, change json_logger() to:
json_logger() {
  jq \
    --arg level "$1" \
    --arg systemid "app-manager-`cat /etc/machine-id`"\
    --arg host `hostname`.${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}\
    --arg time `date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ'`\
    --arg timezone `date +%Z`  <<EOF
{
  "type": "log",
  "host": "$host",
  "level": "$level",
  "systemid": "$systemid",
  "system": "connect-manager",
  "time": "$time",
  "timezone": "$timezone",
  "log": "."
}
EOF

And, honestly, after reading my own post, I don't see the value of even using 'jq' here. Why not make json_logger() like this and get rid of everything else?
json_logger() {
cat <<EOF
{
  "type": "log",
  "host": "$(hostname).${MY_POD_NAMESPACE}",
  "level": "$level",
  "systemid": "app-manager-$(cat /etc/machine-id)",
  "system": "connect-manager",
  "time": "$(date '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%3NZ')",
  "timezone": "$(date +%Z)",
  "log": "."
}
EOF
}

